# I'm starting at zero and need advice:

Tags: product, frontend, interface

My name is Mathias, I'm completely new to web-development and all of this and I would appreciate it if someone can quide me the right way to start learning the basics.

*Very short part to my background:*

I have a small clothing-printing studio, for that I have now two magento2 stores. The stores are set-up on a dedicated server that I am renting, and I had a development team which did all the setup work for me.

Now both stores are ready to use and run well, I can access the magento2 backend and I get along pretty well with setting up basic things like cms pages, blocks, homepage layout and that.

But I'm planning to enter a new world for me, the world of coding. 
Because right now I always need to hire someone, even if it's a tiny thing like changing the wording on the product page. This is not a good solution over the long term. 
I had a shopify-store in the past, and I got along very well on changing small things on product pages and so on within html.

Now I would like to be able make changes to my magento stores as well. 
My dream would be to be able to install and test extensions on my own, 
to create changes on the product page template and other templates on my own, to be able to troubleshoot smaller problems and so on.

In general to have a good understanding of that topic, but my main focus would be the interface/frontend part and look and feel of the stores.

But I'm completely stuck and don't even know how I can access the code of my store, or what is needed to do this and how to connect a needed editor to my server so I can enter the code.

Or how to make a duplicate of my theme to only make changes to this duplicate so I don't ruin my normal store. (This all was very easy in shopify)

**Now to my final question:**

**Where should I start?**

All toturials or learnings that I can find start with setting up magento from scratch, but I already have the store on my server.
And on my server c-panel I have a hard time finding anything.

Is there any toturial out there that can help me at my stage?
Or should I start a learning project and set up a fresh store with one of those toturials out there?

Or maybe it's super easy to set up such an editor where I can edit the code and after that I can start from there?

What would be your suggestion?
I am very happy for every word of help.

Thank you all, best regards
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to web development, Don't try to edit anything directly in your working store.

I recommend you to install local setup for learning. Since magento is a open source you can download it online.

There are lot of tutorials that help you learn magento 2.x.

Some of the tutorials are,

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/index.htm

https://blog.magestore.com/magento-tutorial/